# How do I secure my mobile app using Cognito Sync so that it cannot be reverse engineered and used in rogue apps

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am developing a mobile app game with Unity and I am currently implementing the AWS NET SDK, for Cognito Sync, to allow players to keep their save data online in case they reinstall the app or switch phones.

I have a concern with the security for Cognito Sync, as it seems it only requires that I give it an identity pool id for it to automatically connect to the Cognito Sync service; while I am using the guide in the documentation as a reference.

This worries me as I could imagine that it would be easy to reverse-engineer the identity pool id in order to then use it in a rogue app without having to pay for hosting, while receiving potentially huge bills for me.

Does AWS Cognito have any built in mechanism to prevent this? If not, how would I go about preventing it myself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to clarify one thing before starting my actual answer. Cognito Sync APIs are authenticated APIs and can only be called with valid developer AWS credentials of temporary AWS credentials from Cognito Federated Identity service.

Your identity pool id is used with the Cognito Federated Identity service to get temporary credentials. These temporary credentials are vended based on the type of identity you generate. Authenticated identities are the identities which first use one of the supported authentication provider and then the get credentials. Unauthenticated or guest identities directly communicate with service to get temporary credentials. The privileges associated with these credentials are derived from the corresponding role that developers configure for an identity pool.

The recommended approach to build secure applications is to make sure that you use the authenticated identities in your app. Unauthenticated roles should only be used for granting read only access if required.

I hope this makes sense. You can read more about these concepts in our [dev guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html).

Comment: I am using the temporary AWS credentials. Ideally I would like unauthenticated accounts to be able to sync data for their app, and I have configured it to do so. I am just worried about this generosity could be abused.